# Tracing torrent activity behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, torrent

I've got a question about how it is that one may have their torrent activity traced if you are using a proxy.  Specifically, I have the following behind a "Socksv5 w/ Auth" proxy in the Deluge bittorrent client:

- Peer
- Web seed
- Tracker
- DHT

When I download a torrent, I am using magnet links.  Example link:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:**removed**
&dn=SomeFileNameToDisplay.avi
&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969
&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fzer0day.ch%3A1337&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.com%3A1337
&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969
&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969
```

My understanding is that the magnet link is "peerless" in that all requisite informaiton to begin the torrent is already in the link (i.e. in the example above: the hash code, filename to display, and trackers).  So that rules out the magnet link as the source of exposing my IP address (unless the torrent search engine itself is sharing based on my visiting the site; unlikely).

So once my client receives the magnet link informaiton, it starts downloading parts of the file.  However, if everything I do is pushed through the proxy, how is it that another party can ascertain my IP address?  For what its worth, if I check my "torrent" exposure through a site such as `https://ipleak.net/`, then the address shown is the address I would expect through the proxy.

Thanks.